# Python weird syntax, is this annotation?

Tags: python, annotations

Why this code even works? What kind of syntax is that?
You can put that in the middle of the code and it just passes, adding "some_value" to globals().**annotations**
I know what annotations are, but this...?

```
some_value = 1212
something: some_value
print(globals())
'__annotations__': {'something': 1212}
```

Comment: Yes. You see to have answered your own question.

Comment: It's an annotation. You seem to understand that so what dont you understand exactly? What syntax? I'm confused

Comment: Why purpose does it serve in the middle of a body of a function?